# Change value in one recyclerview from selection of another recyclerview

Tags: android, material-design, android-recyclerview

I have two recyclerviews in same activity I want value of first item to changed as soon as I click on the item of 2nd recyclerView

I have been able to retrieve the selected value of 2nd recyclerView

[image]

I want bank icon to be changed on the selection of color

It gets changed when I reselect or select a new Icon

Comment: Could you post your code??

Answer (score 2):

As for your requirement you have to use onclicklistner in your both recycleview holder and pass callback to both adapter.

your call back interface is:

```
        interface Result(){
        public setposition(int position);
        }


         public BankAdapter(Context context,Arralist<Bank> mList,Result result){
         this.context=context;
         this.mList=mList;
         this.result=result;

         }


        private final OnClickListener mOnClickListener = new MyOnClickListener();

        @Override
        public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(final ViewGroup parent, final int viewType) {
            View view = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.myview, parent, false);
            view.setOnClickListener(mOnClickListener);
            return new MyViewHolder(view);
        }

        The onClick method:

        @Override
        public void onClick(final View view) {
            int itemPosition = mRecyclerView.getChildLayoutPosition(view);
            result.setposition(itemPosition);
        }
```

In your Main  activity:

```
    private int selectedBank= -1;
    private BankAdapter bankAdapter;
    private ColorAdapter colorAdapter;

    bankAdapter=new BankAdapter(this, listBank, new Result(){
    @Override
    public void onClick(,int position) {
        selectedBank=position;
    }
    });

    bankRecyleView.setAdapter(bankAdapter);
```

Same code use in your ColorReycleView Adapter for detecting item click:

```
    colorAdapter=new ColorAdapter(this, listColor, new Result(){
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v,int position) {
    if(selectedBank==-1)
    {
     Toast.makeText(this, "Select bank first", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    else{

    //// Do your code here

    /*  here you get your color postion selected
        remove item from bank list and change with selected color image as per your list
        listBank.add(selectedBank,"changed color image");
        bankAdapter.notifyItemChanged();
     */



    }

    }
    });
    colorRecyleView.setAdapter();
```

Hope it helps.